# keeping clipboard items after closing form

Tags: .net, vb.net

I noticed that on my form close, the clipboard is disposed of.  How would I go about not disposing of any item copied to the clipboard at form close?  Say I wanted to copy something, close the form, then paste that information somewhere else... Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an overloaded version of SetDataObject that lets you specify
whether or not the data should remain in the clipboard after your app closes:

```
Clipboard.SetDataObject(template, True)
```

Comment: so i would do something like this on form close: 
`Dim objClipboard As IDataObject = Clipboard.GetDataObject()` `Clipboard.SetDataObject(objClipboard, True)`